# Is there a way of creating nested navigation list divided into columns?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I'm trying to write html for nested navigation divided into columns.
until now I managed to build a nested navigation list, but when I try to divide main `ul` into columns, all sub menus are disappear.

can someone help me?

Comment: can you please share your existing code ?

Comment: Can i have your code in jsFiddle

Comment: yes please check: http://jsfiddle.net/btfbpevc/

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning different css classes for your various `UI` tags, I've managed to create a sample, Try this:

[Nested Navs](https://jsfiddle.net/59cj3m9n/5/)

Comment: tnx, but this is not what I needed - I need a nested navigation that will split into columns (maybe more than 2). I added an example in jsFiddle and you can see there if you remove the: style=" column-count:2;-webkit-column-count:2;-moz-column-gap:50px;-webkit-column-break-inside:avoid" from first ul there will be one column that works fine. when you split into 2 columns, the sub menus don't open. jsfiddle.net/btfbpevc